# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging use Firebase Storage to store message on FCM?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-storage

I choose the Free plan Firebase for my project. When I push notification to clients, does FCM use Firebase Storage to store my message on Firebase? Is firebase cloud messaging completely free, no using Firebase Storage in FCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCM does not incur any cost to you at any time.  Any storage used by FCM is an implementation detail and may change at any time.

(FYI there is no such product as "Firebase Store". There are products called "Cloud Firestore" and "Cloud Storage for Firebase", but they are unrelated to FCM.)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is completely free at the moment, FCM don't use cloud Firestore or real time database